# Is there a physical interpretation for the diagonal terms of a $\chi$ matrix?

Tags: quantum-operation

I assume $\mathcal{E} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(H))$ is a CPTP map. I call $\{B_i\}$ an orthonormal basis for Hilbert-Schmidt scalar product of $\mathcal{L}(H)$

This quantum map can be decomposed as:

$$\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\sum_{ij} \chi_{ij} B_i \rho B_j^{\dagger}$$

The matrix having for element $\chi_{ij}$ is called the chi-matrix of the process.

**My question are:**

Is there a physical interpretation for the diagonal coefficients of this chi matrix in a general case (i.e interpretation valid for any basis). I know that in quantum error correction theory they might have an importance, but even without Q.E.C can we relate them to some physical property ?

Same question in the particular case the chi-matrix is actually diagonal, is there a general interpretation of the $\chi_{ii}$ ?

Comment: If you change the basis, the $\chi$ matrix also changes considerably (and off-diagonal terms can become partly diagonal and vice-versa. Pretty much the only 'special' case that I can come up with is if you represent the $\chi$ matrix in the Pauli basis - if it is then diagonal the map is known as a _Pauli_ channel, which has some implications in the simulatability of the channel (it's easier to simulate such a channel than a non-Pauli channel)

Comment: I would say that the entries of $\chi$ do not have a physical interpretation in general. This might change if your basis has some sort of interpretation, e.g. in the case of Pauli operators. A basis-independent property is $\mathrm{tr}\chi = \mathrm{tr}\mathcal{E}^\dagger(\mathbb{1})$ measuring whether $\mathcal{E}$ is TP. If $\chi$ is diagonal, you have a Kraus decomposition and for CPTP maps, the diagonal entries form a probability distribution. However, since the Kraus operators are in general unphysical operations (e.g. not TP), the interpretation of those is difficult.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich 'A basis-independent property is $\mathrm{tr}[\chi] = \mathrm{tr}[\mathcal{E}^{\dagger}(1)]$' measuring whether $\mathcal{E}$ is TP.' - isn't this a necessary, but not sufficient condition for $\mathcal{E}$ being TP, for which one should have $\mathcal{E}^{\dagger}(1) = 1$ (not considering trace-decreasing maps)?

Comment: @JSdJ Indeed, this is not sufficient. For instance, we always have $\mathrm{tr} \mathcal{E}^\dagger(1) = \mathrm{tr} \mathcal{E}(1)$, so you cannot even say whether it is TP or unital.